# Cuda thread: special mapping/indexing

Tags: cuda, mapping

I have different blocks of 34 threads each (0...33).

I need to find a formula so that in each of these blocks, the first 33 threads (0...32) will point to the correspondent

```
bases[x]
```

With x from 0 to 32, while the last one, 33, to 66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
int offset = (threadIdx.x == 33) ? threadIdx.x : 0;
int val = bases[threadIdx.x + offset];
```

so that the last thread gets a non zero offset from the thread index within the block. The ternary operator will be evaluated conditionally and won't cause any branch divergence. I would, however, suggest reconsidering using a block size which is not a multiple of the warp size (32). You will be wasting a lot of cores and cycles by doing so. There wouldn't be anything stopping you using a block with 32 threads and having the last two threads perform extra calculations to cover the required 34 operations per block, for example.

Comment: It looks good. Just a question, the 34th thread will spend the same time on the first line as the other 33 ones, or should I need to put a __syncthreads()? @talonmies

Comment: No, you won't need a synchronization barrier for that.